# Highlight strings that matches regex using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn more JavaScript by working on projects I'm interested in so pardon me if this is a very basic question.

I'm trying to build a tool that detects a string of words (preferably a text or JSON file) from the HTML page (in a div).

```
<html>
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="print" id="print"></div>
        <textarea class="textarea" class="answerBox" id="answerBox"></textarea>
        <script>
                var inputBox = document.getElementById('answerBox');
                inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
                    document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
                }
        </script>
        

        
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I've done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/mc3kqj4t/ It's basically still nothing but what I want to do is to type in something in the box, then as soon as I type the text instantly appears on the page but also while that happens I can see if any of the words that I typed contain certain keywords that match a RegEx (for example "fox" and it's permutations "f ox" or something like that). I need to reference an external file because the words need to be updated every now and then.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

1. You can store the input text in a variable and regex in another. (not sure in your case whether both are necessary)
2. Use JavaScript [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace regex matches, with your highlighted HTML.

Please refer to this demo based on your code.

```html
<html>
<title>Vulgarism Sandbox</title>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Try input in the textarea with some text containing `a\w+`</p>
  <div class="print" id="print"></div>
  <textarea class="textarea" class="answerBox" id="answerBox" value="abcde"></textarea>
  <input value="a\w+" id="regexInput" />
  <script>
    var inputBox = document.getElementById('answerBox');
    inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
      const regexInput = new RegExp(document.getElementById('regexInput').value, 'ig');
      const text = document.getElementById('answerBox').value;

      // replace regex matches in input text, and add 'highlight' HTML
      const renderText = text.replace(regexInput, match => `<b>${match}</b>`)
      document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = renderText;
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It somehow applies to what I wanna do, but I also want to have a dynamic list of words I can just replace whenever probably stored in a text file or json file so that I can change the words when I want to. It also seems like it doesn't allow you to add more than one word? but this is a very good start thank you!